# has a web works "hello world " demo using html5

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

this is the [demo](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide10), and the code is :

```
main.js:
  var worker = new Worker('extra_work.js');
  worker.onmessage = function(event) { alert(event.data); };

extra_work.js:
  self.onmessage = function(event) {
    // Do some work.
    self.postMessage("some_data");
  }
```

i use the code to run , but  it cant alert "some_data" ,

so what can i do  ?

thanks

**updated**

i edit the extra_work.js to this :

```
postMessage('aaaa');
```

and the firefox alert 'aaaa', but chrome not ,

so  how to make the chrome alert 'aaaa'

Answer (score 2):

In your example the worker will not start until you call *worker.postMessage()* which invokes the worker's *onmessage* function.

Append this line to main.js for the fix:

```
worker.postMessage(null);
```

**Update**:

*postMessage()* requires an argument (even if null) in Firefox 3.6

I also put together an example that works in Chrome and Firefox for you to see:

http://rob.olmos.name/worker/worker.html

Comment: only use postMessage('aaaa') will be ok , worker will be not found on broswer .

Comment: @zjm1126 You need to have two scripts. One is a file named extra_work.js and the other is just the main.js script in the html page.

Comment: look the updated , i can alert 'aaaa' on firefox , but not in chrome , how can i do it .